# IBM Connections API Profile Tags - how do i add a tag that has spaces as well as setting a tag type

Tags: xml, api, tags, ibm-connections

1. I've been trying to pass this over and it seems like it's automatically splitting "Two-word Term" into two categories namely "Two-word" and "Term". I tried to change the space to %20 and it still doesn't work.
2. How do i set the tag type through the API? It seems like adding snx:type="tag_type" doesn't work.

   <atom:category term="TAG_TERM" snx:frequency="TAG_FREQUENCY" snx:type="TAG_TYPE"></atom:category>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, It's working as it's designed out of the box. [http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Using+IBM+Connections+4.5+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Understanding_profile_tags_ic45&content=pdcontent](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Using%20IBM%20Connections%204.5%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Understanding_profile_tags_ic45&content=pdcontent)

There are a couple things you can do:

1 - URL Encode the tags.  TWO-TERM TAG -> TWO-TERM%20TAG

2 - I also see SPACE commonly translated to + signs

3 - Open a PMR to find out if you can get support for multiple term tags. It's not in the default docs.

Comment: tag type depends on the XSD which defines the acceptable format, you should search your connections server for that file

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I'll check on these and get back to you.